# Create user login page with Android Studio and Socket

Tags: android, node.js, sockets

I want to create a login page for Android Studio and send the socket username to the Worms pass node and save it to the database.
Who can guide me?

Comment: For a generalized guide in doing this, search in Google and create some minimal code. If you have difficulty at any particular point, post the same in SO.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.loopwiki.com/beginner/android-login-register-sqlite-database-tutorial/
https://www.androhub.com/login-signup-and-forgot-password-screen-design-android/

1. create xlm. files
2. for define for user get and set function
3. write databasehelper.class
4. write mainactivity
5. write exceptions /error /toast message code..

good luck:)

Comment: I was trying to make a login page with the   socket but unfortunately it didn't help me